# Is there a way of getting the cystoscape object associated with a DOM element?

Tags: cytoscape.js

I currently do the following:

```
let $cy = $('#cy');
let cy = cytoscape({
   container: $cy,
   ...
});

$cy.data('cytoscape', cy);
```

The above allow me to reobtain the cytoscape object (e.g. in a event handler) as follows:

```
let cy = $cy.data('cytoscape');
```

Is there a builtin method of obtaining the cytoscape object so I can avoid doing all this work (and technically mess with a element own by the library)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is generally assumed that you will keep Cytoscape instance in a shared variable in the code, so you won't need to get it from the DOM object.

You can get the Cytoscape instance associated with a DOM element like this:

```
 document.getElementById('cy')._cyreg.cy
```

Be aware, as far as I know this is not documented.

Comment: Thanks. If you're familiar enough with the library to be able to produce that code, I'm sure there's no official way, and I shall accept your answer immediately :)