# Elements array is empty using cytoscape.js

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

When i use the function add (cy.add(parameters)) from the cytoscape.js library, the "Elements" array is empty when I type cy.elements on firefox console.

Here some images about what i actually said.
Adding some nodes 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJWkY.jpg

Trying to see if in the cytoscape object are properties which match with the letter 'e' and there is no "elements" property
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyinl.jpg

cy.elements is undefined
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQYPS.jpg

Adding a new node

```
let node = cy.add({
      group: 'nodes',
      data: { id: identifier,value:val},
      position: { x:200+Math.floor(Math.random() * 251), y:200+Math.floor(Math.random() * 151) }
    });
```

Adding a new edge

```
      //levelPointer(), lastEdge and lastLevel return an int value
      s = 'n'+(Math.floor(lastEdge/2))+'l'+levelPointer() 
      t = 'n'+(++lastEdge)+'l'+(lastLevel+1)
      let node = cy.add({
        group: 'edges',
        data: {id:s+t,source:s,target:t}
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

The `cy` that you are accessing from the console is not the Cytoscape instance, but the DOM element. My other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52602724/is-there-a-way-of-getting-the-cystoscape-object-associated-with-a-dom-element/52603597#52603597) explains how you can access a Cytoscape instance associated with a DOM element.

If you initialize Cyroscape instance as follows, it will be directly accessible from the console:

```
var cy = window.cy = cytoscape(options);
```

Comment: `let cy= cytoscape({

  container: document.getElementById('cy'),
  //other properties
`
This is how i declared cy object in the file. I tried to put another name but i still have the same problem

Comment: Well, I just gave you two options and looks like you did not use any of them. First option: from the console `var cyInstance = cy._cyreg.cy;` Then you can use `cyInstance.elements()` and other cytoscape methods. The second option is make the cy instance a global variable and store it in `window`. If you write `let cy = window.cy = ` then in the console you can use `window.cy.elements()`